# Unexpected behavior when comparing null to null

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I'm sure this is something completely, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it. I'm trying to check if a variable is null in my react native app, but it's not behaving as I expect. This is a console.log showcasing my issue:

```
    console.log(
        this.props.until,
        this.props.until != null,
        this.props.until !== null,
        !this.props.until,
        !!this.props.until);
```

And this is the output:

```
[null, true, true, false, true]
```

How can the variable be null, but not be compared to null. I thought I had a basic understanding of Typescript, but apparently not.

Thanks for your help, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

There is something wrong in the snipped you provided `null != null` and `null !== null` is always evaluated as false

Comment: Is this.props.until a function? Then it could be evaluated when called on console.log and change its value. Can you post the value of this.props.until?

Comment: No, it's a variable of type "Moment". Its value is null at the point of comparison.

Comment: It's not possible null == null and even null === null. There is something wrong somewhere else but there is not enough code provided to find it

Comment: I know, it doesn't make sense at all! I thought it might be converted to a string "null" somewhere, but when I log typeof it's an object, when I JSON.stringify it it's just "null". No idea what's happening here.